# Cannot install ol3-contextmenu

Tags: node.js, openlayers-3, npm-install

I am unable to install `ol3-contextmenu`.

When i am executing below:

```
npm install ol3-contextmenu --save
```

I am getting below error:

> ERR! closure-util connect ECONNREFUSED 216.58.199.174:80 ..... .....
>   npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
>   /chokidar/fsevents: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating
>   system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.15 npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "ol3-contextmenu" "--save" npm ERR! node v6.2.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! closure-util@1.15.1 postinstall: `node ./bin/closure-util.js
>   update` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   closure-util@1.15.1 postinstall script 'node ./bin/closure-util.js
>   update'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and
>   npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with
>   the closure-util package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell
>   the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node
>   ./bin/closure-util.js update npm ERR! You can get information on how
>   to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   closure-util npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their
>   info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls closure-util npm ERR! There is
>   likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--no-optional` flag as a workaround.

`npm update --no-optional`

Comment: No luck! I tried "npm install ol3-contextmenu --no-optional", "npm install ol3-contextmenu update --no-optional".  Didn't work! Getting errors

Comment: ERR! closure-util connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.112:443
+--UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.1
`--UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.1
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ol3-contextmenu" "--no-optional"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! closure-util@1.15.1 postinstall: `node ./bin/closure-util.js update`
npm ERR! Failed at the closure-util@1.15.1 postinstall script 'node ./bin/closure-util.js update'.